# Connecting 2 IOS Apps Through a Video Call

Tags: ios, swift, video

I've been developing an app and it seems I've ran into a brick wall. I'm trying to create a video connection between two apps (similar to how the uber driver app connects with the uber rider app-etc.) Basically I need to be able to allow one app to create a 1:1 video call to another app. Just a nod in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the most common and reliable approach for this is to use some WebRTC based solution. There are several SDK that provide such an experience. I've used [Sinch](https://www.sinch.com/), [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) and [Icelink](https://www.frozenmountain.com/products-services/icelink/)

Some of them requires you to purchase a license.